# remote trigger an action on apple iwatch

Tags: remote-access, watchos, heartrate

Can I check if there is a way to remote trigger an action to Apple iWatch (WatchOS).

I would like to get information like heartrate, other sensor info ONLY when I make a request for it remotely.

Thanks.